# How to execute WMI call from command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, wmic

I've been using the following instructions to successfully turn my fans to silent mode:

[Fan Overboost stuck on Balanced mode in Rog Gaming Center](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/jrv2lo/fan_overboost_stuck_on_balanced_mode_in_rog/gc491ok?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

The relevant parts are:

> 1. Download and extract WMI Explorer.
> 2. Right click WmiExplorer.exe and select run as administrator.
> 3. In WMI Explorer, click Connect at top left.
> 4. In namespaces box, double click ROOT/WMI.
> 5. In classes box, find Asus ATK class and double click it (note on my laptop the class is called 'WMI:AsusAtkWmi_WMNB
> 6. In instances box, right click the Asus ATK instance, then in the first drop down menu which appears, hover over Execute Method, then left click DEVS in the second drop down menu.
> 7. In Control Status enter 2, in Device ID enter 1114136

However, how can I achieve the same effect but in command prompt/Powershell? I've tried reading the WMIC documentation by Microsoft, but couldn't figure out how to navigate through the namespaces, classes, then instances.

This may be a XY problem, as the reason I am doing this is the call does not persist after the laptop wakes from shutdown or sleep, so any suggestions for the real problem itself is also welcome.

Comment: Take a look in your notebook manual there should be some easy way to do this like an FN key or some switch.

Comment: There is a key combo that controls fan speed, but when I check in the Asus software, it only toggles between balanced and overboost - silent mode is nowhere to be found. I remember seeing silent when I first bought the laptop, but software updates seemed to have removed it.

Comment: Guess you would have to make some test, can you find the "AsusAtkWmi_WMNB" in wmic? for example wmic /? |find /i "AsusAtk" or wmic AsusAtkWmi_WMNB get...?

Comment: Not that this answers your question.. but ALMOST ALL things done through WMI are simple wrappers around native functions.  Are you sure that there isn't a native utility for this

Answer (score 0):

This should work in PowerShell as admin:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class AsusAtkWmi_WMNB).DEVS(1114136, 2)
```

This basically replicates the instructions that you got for WMI Explorer, except in the PowerShell language:

1. find the right WMI object via [Get-WmiObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1), specifying the class name and the namespace in which to look for
2. call the DEVS method on it, pass Device ID as argument 1 and Control Status as argument 2

`Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class AsusAtkWMI_WMNB` will give you basic information about the class, incl. the list of available methods.
`(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class AsusAtkWMI_WMNB).DEVS)` will give you information about the method, in particular, the list and types of arguments.

---

Note that `Get-WmiObject` seems deprecated/superseded by [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.3), and you can run `Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/WMI -Class AsusAtkWMI_WMNB` to get an object that looks the same. I didn't manage to list (or call) WMI methods on the result though; but I know almost nothing about PowerShell so it's likely that I'm missing something very basic.